Is there a way to prevent any USB data transfer for locked Samsung devices?
Just like iPhones are pretty hard to get into once they are locked, due to USB being completely disabled, is there something similar for Samsung, or any Android at all?
This prevents many exploits from being applied to a locked device.
What about prevent from entering DFU mode or any similar mode?

Unclear what you are asking. Are you referring to old patched exploits like: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/09/oatmeal-on-universal-cereal-bus.html or something else? Once physical access to device is achieved, any attacker can get very invasive but it would depend on if the attacker is just trying to unlock the phone OR a nation state level actor.

@MorrisonChang AFAIK, unlike iPhones, Android devices, including Samsungs, generally allow USB data transfer even when locked?

@sfinja: No, that is not true.

@Mavrik I just checked again and you're right. If the device is locked, there is no way to switch the phone's "Use USB for" from No data transfer to File transfer / Android Auto. I must have confused this with debugging via Android Studio while the device is locked (which works for me, once I authenticate the remote PC before locking the device).
